# Numerical Solution of Parametric Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to numerically solve a differential equation $(dx/dt)^2+(dy/dt)^2=dx/dt$. I can't figure out the way to use standard numerical methods (Euler, RK, etc). Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Shah

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. For instance, at a first glance, it seems you have just one equation but two unknown functions...

Comment: Is this the only equation you have? At the moment it appears as though you have two unknown functions: $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ but only a single equation relating them. In order to solve for both $x$ and $y$ you would need two equations.

Comment: Yeah, it is only one ode with two dependent variables x(t) and y(t) and a dependent variable t. This equation is obtained from the equation of cycloid (by eliminating the parameter).